# How can I pass a parameter in Action?

Tags: c#, .net, action

```
private void Include(IList<string> includes, Action action)
{
    if (includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in includes)
            action(<add include here>);
    }
}
```

I want to call it like that

```
this.Include(includes, _context.Cars.Include(<NEED TO PASS each include to here>));
```

The idea is pass each include to the method.

Comment: Is your `Action` just an `Action` or is it an `Action<T>` or any other variation? How many parameters do you want?

Comment: It looks like you're already passing the includes via the `includes` argument.  Is the idea that you want to pass each member of the `includes` list to the `action`?  If so, just pass `_context.Cars.Include` (with no brackets).

Comment: Yes the idea is to pass each include to the method _context.Cars.Include()

Comment: What error are you seeing?  What is the signature of the `_context.Cars.Include` method?  The Scrum Meister's updated answer looks right to me, but I guess the Cars.Include method might need adapting to take a string...?

Comment: Getting error: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Repository.Entity.Car> System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Repository.Entity.Car>.Include(string)' has the wrong return type. Signature is: public ObjectQuery<T> Include(string path);

Answer (score 142, accepted):

If you know what parameter you want to pass, take a `Action<T>` for the type. Example:

```
void LoopMethod (Action<int> code, int count) {
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         code(i);
     }
}
```

If you want the parameter to be passed to your method, make the method generic:

```
void LoopMethod<T> (Action<T> code, int count, T paramater) {
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         code(paramater);
     }
}
```

And the caller code:

```
Action<string> s = Console.WriteLine;
LoopMethod(s, 10, "Hello World");
```

---

Update. Your code should look like:

```
private void Include(IList<string> includes, Action<string> action)
{
    if (includes != null)
    {
         foreach (var include in includes)
             action(include);
    }
}

public void test()
{
    Action<string> dg = (s) => {
        _context.Cars.Include(s);
    };
    this.Include(includes, dg);
}
```

Comment: the idea is to pass each include to the method _context.Cars.Include()

Comment: With this code(code from Update) Getting error: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Repository.Entity.Car> System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Repository.Entity.Car>.Include(string)' has the wrong return type

Comment: @jop Updated, Build a new `Action<string>` delegate that calls the `Cars.Include`. Alternatively, your custom Include method could accept a `Func<string, whatever type Cars.Include() returns>`

Comment: Convention is that generic variant should have argument T named arg, not parameter.

Answer (score 20):

You're looking for [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx), which takes a parameter.

Comment: You may want to add a second `T`.

Comment: the idea is to pass each include to the method _context.Cars.Include()

Answer (score 20):

Dirty trick: You could as well use lambda expression to pass any code you want including the call with parameters.

```
this.Include(includes, () =>
{
    _context.Cars.Include(<parameters>);
});
```

Comment: I like this because I had a utility class already used in many places that didn't accept an `Action<T>` - this lets me still use that without modification.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, but it's so easy.

Comment: This is what I do use, with a BlockingCollection of Action(s) to simulate what I have with C++/Qt (the signal/slot mechanism)