# Execute Method Before and After Code Block

Tags: c#, .net

How could I wrap some code in brackets to do the following?

```
MyCustomStatement(args){
// code goes here
}
```

So that before the code in the brackets executes, it'll call a method and when the code in the brackets finishes executing it will call another method. Is there such a thing? I know it seems redundant to do this when I can simply call the methods before and after the code and all, but I simply was curious. I don't know how to word this exactly because I'm new to programming.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What do you mean by "wrap some code in brackets"?

Comment: You mean you want to create an event? see [Events (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)

Comment: Apply [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Comment: Have you looked at AOP.  Try downloading the PostSharp demo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by storing the code in an abstract class that executes the "before" and "after" code for you when you call `Run()`:

```
public abstract class Job
{
    protected virtual void Before()
    {
        // Executed before Run()
    }

    // Implement to execute code
    protected abstract void OnRun();

    public void Run()
    {
        Before();
        OnRun();
        After();
    }

    protected virtual void After()
    {
        // Executed after Run()
    }
}

public class CustomJob : Job
{
    protected override void OnRun()
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

And in the calling code:

```
new CustomJob().Run();
```

Of course then for every piece of custom code you'll have to create a new class, which may be less than desirable.

An easier way would be to use an `Action`:

```
public class BeforeAndAfterRunner
{
    protected virtual void Before()
    {
        // Executed before Run()
    }

    public void Run(Action actionToRun)
    {
        Before();
        actionToRun();
        After();
    }

    protected virtual void After()
    {
        // Executed after Run()
    }
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
public void OneOfYourMethods()
{
    // your code
}

public void RunYourMethod()
{
    new BeforeAndAfterRunner().Run(OneOfYourMethods);
}
```

Comment: Good answer. How can I call OneOfYourMethods method with parameters  and how can I receive return value of the method.

Comment: @suphero see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738533/dispatch-invoke-new-action-with-a-parameter, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965508/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-in-action

Answer (score 3):

To literally achieve what you want, you can use a delegate:

```
Action<Action> callWithWrap = f => {
    Console.WriteLine("Before stuff");
    f();
    Console.WriteLine("After stuff");
};

callWithWrap(() => {
    Console.WriteLine("This is stuff");
});
```

This requires adding "weird syntax" to your blocks and an understanding of how delegates and anonymous functions in C# work. More commonly, if you're doing this within a class, use the technique demonstrated in @CodeCaster's answer.