# Is there a generic way to call another method whenever a method is called in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a method something like this:

```
public Something MyMethod()
{
    Setup();

    Do something useful...

    TearDown();

    return something;
}
```

The Setup and TearDown methods are in the base class.

The problem I'm having is that I have to write this type of method over and over again with the Setup() and TearDown() method calls.

**EDIT: The tricky part of this method is that "Do something useful..." is specific to this method only.  This part is different for every method I create.**

**Also, I can have MyMethod2, MyMethod3, in a single class.  In all cases, I would like to run the setup and teardown**

Is there an elegant way of doing this without having to write this every single time?

Perhaps I'm delusional, but is a way to add an attribute to the method and intercept the method call, so I can do stuff before and after the call?

Comment: This is a duplicate of plenty of questions. Did you try searching? You can use delegates, events, abstract methods, aspect-oriented programming and so on. For example [Run a method before all methods of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192709/run-a-method-before-all-methods-of-a-class), [Call base function then inherited function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747711/), [Execute code before the called function is executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398530), [Execute Method Before and After Code Block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484206/)and so on.

Comment: You want to use Aspect Oriented Programming. There are a lot of tools for that.

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster, but none of the postings you mentioned help in my case because in my case I can have many of these "MyMethods" in a single class with different method names, different parameters, and different return values.

Comment: Use "@username" to notify someone of your reply. I have reopened your question.

Comment: Anyway why don't the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484206/execute-method-before-and-after-code-block) help?

Comment: This requires refactoring, and not enough information is given to suggest the proper approach to use in the refactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx), [lambdas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) like so:

```
public SomeThing MyMethod()
{
    return Execute(() =>
    {
        return new SomeThing();
    });
}


public T Execute<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    if (func == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("func");

    try
    {
        Setup();

        return func();
    }
    finally
    {
        TearDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the closest to what I was thinking, but the main point was to remove having to write setup/teardown repeatedly.  This code removes it but adds extra layer of code.

Comment: You should look at AOP frameworks if you want to use attributes to solve this problem.

Answer (score 8):

Just implement this method in abstract base class like this:

```
public Something MyMethod()
{
    Setup();

    DoSomethingUsefull();

    TearDown();

    return something;
}

protected abstract DoSomethingUsefull();
```

Now you need to override only one method in inherited classes - DoSomethingUsefull()

This is Template Method pattern

Comment: Template pattern -- very nice.

Comment: Usually I would make `DoSomethingUseful` protected in similar case.

Comment: Yes, protected should be here, my bad

Comment: @DenisEfimov They why don't you [edit your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34437062/edit) and fix it?